# How to zip every element of array to every element of another array in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, merge

Say I have this array:

```
[0, 1, 4], [2, 3]
```

How can I merge them to get:

```
[0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,3], [4,2], [4,3]
```

I tried:

```rb
[0, 1, 4].zip [2, 3]
```

But I got:

```
[[0, 2], [1, 3], [4, nil]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[0, 1, 4].product([2, 3])
```

That should generate:

```
[[0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```